# Is it possible to limit a JavaScript variable size in bits?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a networked game. Thus, I have to send information to clients many times a second. One of these pieces of information is position that is limited to a 500x500 field. It would be great if I could simply send 2.25 bytes (1.25 bytes per x/y). However, as far as I am aware, I am going to end up sending a massive floating point number.

So is there any to limit the numbers to a certain bit count?

Comment: Taking your question literally, no it is not possible. The javascript virtual machine has that taken care of for you. You can do this easily in C or C++ though.

Comment: Have you looked into bitwise operators to combine values?

Comment: @rhughes What do you mean? Doesn't that still use 32 bit numbers?

Comment: @self I know this might be ugly, but could I make a 9 bit Boolean array and send that?

Comment: no `ecmascript` defines JavaScript numbers as 64 bit floating point. We don't get integers in javascript

Comment: Are you sending this info the clients? Across a network? To other node.js installs on the same machine? Different machines?

Comment: If you communicate over web sockets you can send binary and unpack those from a `Uint8Array`.

Comment: ^^^ This is why I was asking

Comment: sure you can do that but that isn't really limiting the size of a variable in javascript

Comment: Using a typed array is the only way to affect the storage size of numbers. An ordinary JavaScript number is **always** a double-precision value. (The verb *send* is used a couple times, so it leads me to believe that the issue is transmission time and not so much memory use at the client.)

Comment: @Pointy That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @self perhaps I used the wrong wording, I should have used `number` rather than `variable`. `Uint8Array` seems to do just that.

Comment: It is also not clear whether there's an actual performance difference between sending a packet with a payload of 2 bytes vs. 10 bytes given the other overhead (both TCP and webSocket framing) involved and the fact that it all goes in one packet anyway.

Comment: If you are using socket.io there is an explanation of binary data transmission here. http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not. As @Pointy states in the comments, your best **simple** bet is to send a typed `Array` to clients via WebSockets. You could also make some significant improvements to transmitted payload size using a custom compression algorithm if you know that the position matrix/`Array` will be very sparse.